# Creating a server side process that retrieves an Auth0 Management API v2 token in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, c#-3.0, auth0

I'm new to C# and am trying to create a process on my backend that will retrieve a JWT token for the auth0 Management API V2 to use with user profiles and such as outlined in this: https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/get-access-tokens-for-production#get-access-tokens

The issue I'm having is I'm unclear on a few things... 
  How do I make a post request with params and headers without using restsharp?
  Presumably I would create a function that runs at startup to retrieve this long living token and then it would need to run again every time the token would be about to expire. I'm thinking this function would live in the ConfigureServices method of my startup.cs but I'm unclear on what the correct syntax for any of that would be and really can't seem to google a good resource to help me learn that. How do I create this function?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I make a post request with params and headers without using restsharp?

In ASP.NET Core app, you can use IHttpClientFactory to create an HttpClient instance, then make HTTP request(s) to API endpoint(s).

For detailed information, please check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1

> I would create a function that runs at startup to retrieve this long living token and then it would need to run again every time the token would be about to expire.

If you'd like to monitor `expires_in` time of your acquired token, you can run a background task to check current time and `expires_in` time, and acquire a new one if the existing token is going to be expired.